# GlassFish Java web service timeout

Tags: java, c#, web-services, web-applications, glassfish

I'm setting up a new GlassFish Server 4.1.1 with one Java web service deployed on it. The web service has one web method, which receives JSON as an input parameter and as result it also returns a JSON. To serialize/deserialize Java objects to/from JSON I'm using the Gson library. The web method is calling an other web service and one run is executing approximately 2-3 minutes. I'm calling this web service for example 6-10 times in a loop, so the web method is waiting approximately 16-30 minutes to return a value. The problem is timeout, but I don't know where and how to set it for my problem.

I try to call this Java web service from a Visual Studio C# project, where I added a web reference where I defined the web reference URL of the web service. I also set the time for how long should the XML Web service client wait for the reply to a synchronous XML Web service request to arrive. I set it to 10 hours as is shown below.

```cs
static string CallEARSjDE(string json)
{
    EARSWebReference.EARSWebService EARSWS = new EARSWebReference.EARSWebService();
    EARSWS.Timeout = 36000000;    // 10 hours

    return EARSWS.EARSjDE(json);
}
```

I also set a timeout for a web service request I make in the Java web method. I set it to 1 hour.

```java
Gson gson = new Gson();
RequestConfig requestConfig = RequestConfig.custom().setConnectTimeout(1 * 3600000).build();   // timeout set to 1 hour
HttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().setDefaultRequestConfig(requestConfig).build();
HttpPost post = new HttpPost(this.ServiceURL);
StringEntity postingString = new StringEntity(gson.toJson(problemLCSRequest));
post.setEntity(postingString);
post.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(post);
HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
String responseString = EntityUtils.toString(entity, "UTF-8");

ProblemLCSResponse responseJson = gson.fromJson(responseString, ProblemLCSResponse.class);
```

Besides these two timeouts I also set a timeout in GlassFish admin console. I did it in Configurations → server-config → Web Container section where I set the session timeout to 36.000 seconds (10 hours).

For example, when I call a web service inside a web method 6 times I get the desired response. But when I call the web service more than 6 times, it throws me an exception shown below. I think the reason for this exception is in the timeout, but I don't know which one causes it and where can I change it.

> Warning:   StandardWrapperValve[EARSWebService]: Servlet.service() for servlet EARSWebService threw exception
>   java.nio.channels.ClosedByInterruptException
>       at java.nio.channels.spi.AbstractInterruptibleChannel.end(AbstractInterruptibleChannel.java:202)
>       at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.write(SocketChannelImpl.java:478)
>       at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOUtils.flushByteBuffer(TCPNIOUtils.java:149)
>       at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOUtils.writeCompositeBuffer(TCPNIOUtils.java:87)
>       at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOAsyncQueueWriter.write0(TCPNIOAsyncQueueWriter.java:129)
>       at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOAsyncQueueWriter.write0(TCPNIOAsyncQueueWriter.java:106)
>       at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.AbstractNIOAsyncQueueWriter.write(AbstractNIOAsyncQueueWriter.java:260)
>       at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.AbstractNIOAsyncQueueWriter.write(AbstractNIOAsyncQueueWriter.java:169)
>       at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.AbstractNIOAsyncQueueWriter.write(AbstractNIOAsyncQueueWriter.java:71)
>       at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransportFilter.handleWrite(TCPNIOTransportFilter.java:126)
>       at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.TransportFilter.handleWrite(TransportFilter.java:191)
>       at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$8.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:111)
>       at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:283)
>       at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:200)
>       at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:132)
>       at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:111)
>       at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
>       at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.FilterChainContext.write(FilterChainContext.java:890)
>       at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.FilterChainContext.write(FilterChainContext.java:858)
>       at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.io.OutputBuffer.flushBuffer(OutputBuffer.java:1029)
>       at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.io.OutputBuffer.flushBinaryBuffers(OutputBuffer.java:1016)
>       at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.io.OutputBuffer.flushAllBuffers(OutputBuffer.java:987)
>       at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.io.OutputBuffer.flush(OutputBuffer.java:738)
>       at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.doFlush(OutputBuffer.java:291)
>       at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.flush(OutputBuffer.java:275)
>       at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteOutputStream.flush(CoyoteOutputStream.java:175)
>       at java.io.FilterOutputStream.flush(FilterOutputStream.java:140)
>       at com.ctc.wstx.io.UTF8Writer.flush(UTF8Writer.java:103)
>       at com.ctc.wstx.sw.BufferingXmlWriter.flush(BufferingXmlWriter.java:225)
>       at com.ctc.wstx.sw.BaseStreamWriter.flush(BaseStreamWriter.java:259)
>       at com.sun.xml.ws.util.xml.XMLStreamWriterFilter.flush(XMLStreamWriterFilter.java:71)
>       at com.sun.xml.ws.streaming.XMLStreamWriterUtil.getOutputStream(XMLStreamWriterUtil.java:103)
>       at com.sun.xml.ws.message.jaxb.JAXBMessage.writePayloadTo(JAXBMessage.java:403)
>       at com.sun.xml.ws.message.AbstractMessageImpl.writeTo(AbstractMessageImpl.java:192)
>       at com.sun.xml.ws.api.message.MessageWrapper.writeTo(MessageWrapper.java:226)
>       at com.sun.xml.ws.encoding.StreamSOAPCodec.encode(StreamSOAPCodec.java:144)
>       at com.sun.xml.ws.encoding.SOAPBindingCodec.encode(SOAPBindingCodec.java:242)
>       at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter.encodePacket(HttpAdapter.java:636)
>       at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter.access$100(HttpAdapter.java:108)
>       at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter$HttpToolkit.handle(HttpAdapter.java:878)
>       at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter.handle(HttpAdapter.java:422)
>       at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.ServletAdapter.handle(ServletAdapter.java:169)
>       at org.glassfish.webservices.JAXWSServlet.doPost(JAXWSServlet.java:169)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:318)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
>       at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
>       at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:416)
>       at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:283)
>       at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
>       at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
>       at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:206)
>       at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:180)
>       at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
>       at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
>       at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:283)
>       at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:200)
>       at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:132)
>       at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:111)
>       at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
>       at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:536)
>       at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
>       at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
>       at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
>       at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
>       at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:591)
>       at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:571)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Comment: Monitor if your Web Service is still running before calling it. I think this is your problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, I found the right timeout to set. I had to go to the admin panel and inside `Configurations → server-config → Network Config` I had to set the **HTTP Request Timeout** of http-listener-1.